# Read txt files in Matlab contain symbols in two first rows

Tags: matlab, file, file-io, import

I have data which are as the following :
MTtmax6000_N1000000_k+0.1_k-T0.001_k-D0.1_kh1.txt

```
# nMT=1000000 tmax=60000 trelax=10000 k+=0.1 k-T=0.001 k-D=0.1 kh=1
#t (L-L0) L varL NGTP varNGTP Cap varCap
0  0  50090.2  2089.48     0.100257  0.100158   0.104798     0.114295
100  0.897735  50091.1  2109.92     0.099841  0.0998968   0.104373     0.114029
200  1.80163  50092  2130.83     0.099736  0.0995947   0.104204     0.113554
300  2.70513  50092.9  2151.79     0.099775  0.0997319   0.104323     0.113928
400  3.60867  50093.9  2172.17     0.099982  0.0999776   0.104546     0.114294
500  4.50984  50094.8  2192.49     0.100229  0.100263   0.104795     0.114473
600  5.40802  50095.6  2213.72     0.100149  0.100159   0.10463     0.114101
700  6.3161  50096.6  2234.2     0.099856  0.100117   0.10433     0.114139
800  7.21386  50097.5  2254.76     0.099624  0.0997151   0.104171     0.113879
900  8.11601  50098.4  2275.18     0.100183  0.100386   0.104615     0.114237
1000  9.01724  50099.3  2296.13     0.100504  0.100423   0.105058     0.114745
1100  9.92572  50100.2  2317.11     0.100368  0.10056   0.105023     0.115089
1200  10.8262  50101.1  2338.26     0.099476  0.0998665   0.103951     0.113913
1300  11.7243  50102  2359.96     0.099775  0.0997559   0.104246     0.113753
1400  12.6273  50102.9  2381.2     0.100081  0.100099   0.104571     0.11406
1500  13.5297  50103.8  2401.8     0.099702  0.0997495   0.104267     0.114045
1600  14.4281  50104.7  2422.56     0.099792  0.0999496   0.104292     0.113975
1700  15.3369  50105.6  2443.44     0.099912  0.0999296   0.104452     0.114242
```

I tried to read these data by using dlmread, txtscan or textread when I implement the code I receive this massage:

Error using dlmread (line 139) Mismatch between file and format string. Trouble reading number from file (row 1u, field 1u) ==> # nMT=1000000 tmax=4000 trelax=1000 k+=1 k-T=0.01 k-D=0.1 kh=1\n

I want command to read txt files and ignore two first rows.Any help would be greatly appreciated. I will be grateful to you.

```
     clc;
        clear all;
        close all;
        %%
        tic
        Values11 = zeros(225,6);
        K_minus_t =[0.01];
        K_minus_d = [0.1];
        %k_plus =[0.1 0.2 0.4 0.7 1 1.1 1.2 1.5 1.7 2 2.5 3 3.5 4 5];
        m=length(K_minus_t);
        r=length(K_minus_d);
        kk=0;
        ll=1;
        for l=1:r
        for j=1:m
        h=[1];
        k_plus =[1];
        K_minus_T =K_minus_t(j);
        K_minus_D = K_minus_d(l);
        sets = {k_plus, K_minus_T, K_minus_D,h};
        [x,y,z r] = ndgrid(sets{:});
        cartProd = [x(:) y(:) z(:) r(:)];
        nFiles = size(cartProd,1);
        filename{nFiles,j}=[];
        for i=1:nFiles
            %% MT_Sym_N1000000_k+1_k-T0.01_k-D0.1_kh1.txt
            filename{i,j} = ['MT_Sym_N1000000_' ...        
                'k+'  num2str(cartProd(i,1)) '_' ...
                'k-T' num2str(cartProd(i,2),'%6.3g') '_' ...
                'k-D' num2str(cartProd(i,3)) '_' ...
                'kh'  num2str(cartProd(i,4)) '' ...
                '.txt'];
            file1=dlmread(filename{i,j})
            %% line (length)
            t= file1(:,1);
            dline= file1(:,2);
            [coef_line1,s]= polyfit(t, dline, 1);
            coef_line(i,:)= coef_line1;
            v1{i}=s.R;
            v2{i}=s.df;
            v3{i}=s.normr;
            Dl(i)=sqrt (v3{i}/length(t));
    end
    end
end
```

Comment: You also need to tell us the exact code/commands you have tried with `dlmread`, `textscan` and `textread`.

Comment: A way of doing it is creating  function thatread that type of file,  hardcoding 2 line reads i the beggining and the reading line by line until file ends. Not to hard to do. see `fgets`

Comment: I put the code at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`importdata`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html):

```
x = importdata('file.txt',' ',2); %// ' ': col separator; 2: number of header lines
data = x.data; %// x.data is what you want
```

The first line gives a struct `x`  with `data`, `textdata` and `colheaders` fields. The numeric data is in field `data`,  so `x.data` is what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much Luis Mendo